# How to filter a text in Paragraph using "filter in angular JS"

Tags: angularjs-directive

I need a way to filter the text in paragraph based on text entered in text box. below is the code.

Please help me on this.

```
<p>Filtering input:</p>

<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

<p filter:test> this is sample angular JS application </p>
```